# drawElements with multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to render multiple attribute buffers with drawElements:

```js
var verteces = [1,1, 0,-1, -1,0];
var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verteces), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


var colors = [1,0,0,1, 0,1,0,1, 0,0,1,1];
var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


var indices = [0,3,2];
var elBuffer = gl.createBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

If I run this code with `gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);` it renders a beautiful triangle with rbg fill. But if I call `gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 3, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);` I get

```
[.CommandBufferContext.Offscreen-MainThread-0AB44528]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

Can’t figure out what is wrong here. `drawElements` without setting up colors buffer works alright.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu proivide vertex data for 3 vertices, so the only valid vertex indices are `0,1,2`. Yet, you try to render with an index array of `0,3,2`, which will try to acces a fourth vertex, and would result in an out-of-bounds access to the vertex buffers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Shame on me.